# iOS In-App purchase code crashes sometimes (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swift3

I followed [this](http://appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/) tutorial to add In-App purchase (IAP) in my iOS app. Good tutorial, the purchasing part works.

However, if I return from the `UIViewController` that contains the IAP code too quickly, the app crashes, sometimes (without any proper log).

The SKProductsRequest is wrapped in dispatch_async but that doesn't seem to help.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) { [unowned self] in
    ...
    productRequest.delegate = self
    productRequest.start()
}
```

Then calling the UI update on the main thread.

```
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    if response.products.count != 0 {
        print("This doesn't get printed when CRASH happens.")
    }
    ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Any tips on fixing this?

Comment: Could you add the stack trace?

Comment: Try changing `[unowned self]` to `[weak self]` and check `self` for `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this and update later. Working on something else.